# Testing ng-change with Jasmine test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am using this directive to delay the ng-change function from being called. I am forced to use Angular 1.2.4 so I don't have the option of using debounce.

I just needed some help writing tests for this. I think I need to trigger the ng-change somehow in a Jasmine test, but can't figure it out. Here is what I have so far:

```
describe('ng delay', function() {

  var html = '<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-change="change()" ng-delay="500" />';

  beforeEach(inject(function($injector) {
    $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
    $scope = $injector.get('$rootScope').$new();

    $scope.model = '';
    $scope.change = function() {
      console.log('change');
    });
  }));

  it('should have a 500ms delay', function() {
    var elm = compileFunction(html, $scope),
    input = elm.find('input');
    input.trigger('input');
  });
});
```

The change function isn't being called, however. Just any thoughts on how to test this would be a real help.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to delay `ngChange` I suggest another solution which is way easier to test :)

1. in your template you have 
   `<input ng-change="codeChanged()">`
2. in your controller you add

   var timeout;
      $scope.codeChanged = function(){
               if(timeout){
                   $timeout.cancel(timeout);
               }

   ```
           timeout = $timeout(function(){
               $http({
                   method: "GET",
              ...
               }).success(function(data){
                 ...});
           }, 500);

       };
   ```